# Are measurable functions ever/commonly referred to simply as "variables" in the literature on probability?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr F, P)$ be a probability space and $(E, \mathscr E)$ a measurable space.  A measurable function $X:\Omega\to E$ is called a random variable.

If instead we were to drop the probability measure $P$ and simply consider measurable functions from $(\Omega, \mathscr F)$ to $(E, \mathscr E)$, I'd be inclined to call such functions "variables" (or perhaps "pre-random variables") instead of "random variables).

Is this terminology ever/commonly used?

Comment: As I know, in general probability spaces a random variable is defined as a measurable function $X:\Omega\to E$, not any function. And a function being measurable has nothing to do with the measure itself, the definition of measurable function uses only the sigma algebras. (the inverse image of every set in $\mathscr{E}$ has to be in $\mathscr{F}$)

Comment: @Mark Typo by omission.  Please see the edited question.

Comment: Oh, I guess I understand what you mean. No, I never heard of such terminology.

Comment: As also pointed out by Mark, I would understand that you can talk about random variables even if you do not have a probability measure (but then you can't talk about expectation, variance, moments, etc.). I don't think you would have any problems if you just kept calling those things "random variables" and moved on with your life.

Comment: @IvoTerek I guess I'll take that as a "no."